# Get more Microsoft text-to-speech voices

Tags: windows, text-to-speech, text-to-speech-voices, narrator

I am using Windows 10 and want to get more voices for Microsoft at the moment I only have two options: Microsoft Hazel and Microsoft Zira.

Does anyone know how I can get more options?

Comment: So how come you didn't find the link in my answer? ;) By the way it wasn't my downvote.

Comment: @DavidPostill Ok I do have those voices on my pc but this is not the place that I was looking. I am trying to get new voices for the text-to-speech found in windows narrator and through ease of access-> use computer without display -> set up Text to Speech

Comment: My answer also tells you where you can download **new** voices ...

Comment: Plain links are problematic  It helps to explain them to provide some context.

Comment: Seem that the answers here need some updates... Would be great to be able to install new TTS voices these using powershell. Where are MS hiding these?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Does anyone know how I can get more voices?

> You can download some more voices from many free TTS voices (which may not be so good). One of the sources for downloading free Microsoft and LTS TTS voices is [Zero2000](http://www.zero2000.com/free-text-to-speech-natural-voices.html). You can also purchase very high quality TTS voices for Windows from companies like [Ivona](http://www.ivona.com/), [Cepstral](https://www.cepstral.com/) or [CereProc](http://www.cereproc.com/).

Source [Choose Text-to-Speech Voice in Windows 10](http://www.trishtech.com/2015/09/choose-text-to-speech-voice-in-windows-10/)

Answer (score 2):

> Narrator for Windows (all versions) has a few built-in options for male and female voices.

[To set Narrator voice options](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/reader_set_voice_options.mspx?mfr=true) (Microsoft)

Here is a good source for more voices:

[Best Free Windows Narrator Voices You Can Use](http://www.zero2000.com/articles/best-free-windows-narrator-voices-you-can-use.html) (Zero2000.com)

Excerpt:

> In the world of today, more and more people use the text to speech
>   computer technology to free their eyes and save time. As a vital
>   component of the text to speech technology, voices, i.e. speech
>   engines, are the core of text to speech software. Because text to
>   speech software need to invoke voices to synthetic speech and output
>   spoken audio.
>
> There are many voices available on the Internet today, such as AT&T
>   Natural Voices, Cepstral voices, IVONA voices, CereProc voices,
>   NeoSpeech voices, etc.. But most of these voices are commercial and
>   the prices are even higher than the prices of normal text-to-speech
>   software. For example, the prices of AT&T Natural Voices are $35 (base
>   required) plus $35 per additional voice, and the prices of Cepstral
>   voices are &29.99 per voice.
>
> Fortunately, there are also enough high-quality free voices we can
>   use. Most of them are compatible with the Microsoft SAPI 4 or SAPI 5.
>   Generally, the higher SAPI version, the better quality.
>
> Here is the free voices list sorted by the recommended degree.
>
> Microsoft Mike, Mary and Sam -
>
> Microsoft Sam is the default English male voice shipped with Microsoft
>   Windows 2000 and Windows XP. Though not the default, Microsoft Sam is
>   also available in Windows Vista Home Premium. It is used by Narrator,
>   the screen reader program built into the operating system.
>
> Microsoft Mike and Microsoft Mary are optional male and female voices
>   respectively with better quality, available for download from the
>   Microsoft website or other third party text-to-speech related
>   websites.
>
> The most noticeable feature of these three voices is there are both
>   SAPI 4 and SAPI 5 versions of them. SAPI 5 voices are only available
>   on Windows 2000 and later Windows NT-based operating systems. As an
>   exception, the SAPI 5 versions of these voices cannot be installed on
>   Windows Vista and Windows 7. The SAPI 4 versions are more compatible.
>   They can be installed and used on Windows 98 and all the later Windows
>   operating systems.
>
> Microsoft Anna -
>
> Microsoft Anna is the default English voice shipped with Windows Vista
>   and Windows 7. Microsoft Anna is a SAPI 5-only voice and is designed
>   to sound more natural than the previous system default voice Microsoft
>   Sam.
>
> This excellent female voice is base on the new Microsoft SAPI 5.3/5.4.
>   So you cannot use it on Windows XP directly and also there is no
>   standalone installer of this voice on the Microsoft website. The only
>   way to use this fantastic voice on Windows XP is by the Microsoft
>   Streets & Trips. The Microsoft Streets & Trips 2006 and later versions
>   install the voice and the new Microsoft SAPI onto Windows XP computers
>   for the voice-prompt direction feature.
>
> Some third party text-to-speech related websites supply smaller
>   repacked Microsoft Anna installers for Windows XP users. However, it's
>   incomplete and not working correctly on Windows XP because the SAPI
>   version of Windows XP is 5.1.
>
> Lernout & Hauspie Voices -
>
> Lernout & Hauspie Speech Products, or L&H, was a leading Belgium-based
>   speech recognition technology company. This company released dozens of
>   high-quality SAPI 4 voices across multiple languages, including ten
>   American English voices and two British English voices.
>
> In addition, Lernout & Hauspie Michael and Michelle are also optional
>   male and female voices licensed by Microsoft from Lernout & Hauspie,
>   and available through Microsoft Office XP and Microsoft Office 2003 or
>   Microsoft Reader.
>
> Most of the above voices can be found on the Microsoft's website or
>   downloaded directly from the 2nd Speech Center web site. [Click here](http://www.zero2000.com/free-text-to-speech-natural-voices.html) to
>   download them immediately.

Comment: your link to Zero2000.com was already provided by David Postill...

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that one other person provided a link.  I didn't verify it.  In this answer the excerpt actually spells out what is said there, to protect against link-rot.

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer for 2023:

You can get several voices from Windows. Just go to language setting and enable/download tts for Canadian/Australian/England and Indian languages.

You will get about 8 English TTS voices.