# How to get all SAPI 5 English (and other languages) voices for Windows 10

Tags: text-to-speech, text-to-speech-voices

Already looked into other similar questions and the answers did not produce the desired result. For example, one of the suggested solutions provided [this link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/download-voices-for-immersive-reader-read-mode-and-read-aloud-4c83a8d8-7486-42f7-8e46-2b0fdf753130). However, did not allow for more than 1 voice.

Please look into [this link](http://www.oddcast.com/home/demos/tts/tts_example.php)
All the voices here are "supposed" to be available for windows.
How can I download all those voices for free, for Windows 10 (English and other languages)?

Answer (score 3):

I believe that this is what you might be looking for?

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27224

I followed the instructions and it? I know that it says windows 7, but I was able to get it to run on balabolka on windows 10.

I can't leave a comment, so could you clarify what you are using it for? I won't know how to help otherwise.

If that doesn't work, let me know.

Comment: I am writing movie scripts, then record the voices and put them into a video. Don't want my own voice but the OS voices

Comment: Tried those files, they install themselves under SpeechAPI 11, which doesn't come with Windows 10 but can be installed [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27225).

Comment: Link is dead (2021-07-25)

Comment: I just checked (a year later), but the link is not dead.

Comment: this shows how to install them https://superuser.com/questions/590779/how-to-install-more-voices-to-windows-speech?rq=1